# how to get userid in asp.net core api project?

Tags: visual-studio, rest, asp.net-core

previously I was using AspNet `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` to get the current user ID accessing api with following code

```
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Now I migrated whole project from AspNet to AspNetCore but how can I get current user ID accessing api?

Tried following code which returned username

```
var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
```

I googled and found I have to use the following code to get userID,

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

but it returned with **204, No Content**

Comment: Try User.Identity.Name

Comment: I am able to get the name, what I am looking for is to get userID

Comment: I see. Have you considered retrieving the whole user info using the user manager? `await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);` You can inject the UserManager<AppUser> via constructor

Comment: I need user ID field not name

Comment: Exactly, you can use the name to get the user along with his ID.

Comment: suggested code returns: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You mean `User.Identity.Name` is null?How you get the User?

Comment: ```User.Identity.Name``` returns username, ```await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name)```  returns System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: If you try to use `await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Email);`,will it be solved?

Comment: @YiyiYou it also returns ```System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at lambda_method203(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to get current user ID by adding the following code

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public YOURController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        YOURDbContext = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

Then in your Get Methode

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync()
{
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
        var userId = user?.Id;
        return Ok(userId);
}
```